# Seeking tool to geocode USA addresses?

Tags: geocoding, software-recommendations, united-states, google

I have a 6000 USA addresses in form: Address, City, State and ZIP . I want to geocode these addresses. I have tried to use QGIS MMQGIS plugin with geocode tool using Google services, but I have got the message: "Exceeded daily limit".

Is there any tool or free geocoder which is good for USA addresses?

Comment: Your question title and body are not in alignment, and your tags don't match the question, either.

Comment: there have been a lot of posts recently on the mmqgis plugin failing with the google maps API... check the recent mmqgis tags to see if anyone found a solution.